# Find in files list of values

Tags: search, find-and-replace

I have a list of values, and I need find each value one by one in a folder (and its sub-folders) with files, and then save the results (list of files for each entry). Is there any tools to do this? Windows is preferred, but Linux is ok too.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -l value folder folder/* > results_for_value.txt
```

or, if "sub-folders" means to any depth

```
find folder -exec grep -l value {} \; > results_for_value.txt
```

but perhaps you want to read the man page for `locate`

```
locate value …
```

Comment: One could obviously wrap this in a `while read value … ; do` (your grep stuff) `; done < file_with_values.txt`.